# Should I provide my insurance policy number after returning a rental car without any damage (USA)?

Tags: car-rentals, insurance

A car rental company charged me with a security deposit when I was renting the car. I returned the car in original condition and with extra gas in the tank. They have not returned my security deposit yet. Today, they called me and asked me to give them my car insurance policy number to return the security deposit. Should I give them that policy number? I do not trust them, is this normal?

Comment: Did a representative check the car when it was returned, and give you a copy of the inspection report? And if you just dropped it off, did you take photos or a video? It feels as though they want to file against your insurance, and I would not share that info until you know what's going on.

Comment: How long ago was the return? Sounds like a fishy agency. I have never heard of this, and I rent dozens of cars every year, for decades.

Comment: Which cat company is it ???  Bizarre.

Comment: @user9224 please post an update in the comment section. I'm curious to see what happened,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not normal. Do not give them your insurance number. If this is a national rental car company call the customer help line as soon as possible. If this is a local company with just one or a handful of locations, ask to speak to the owner or general manager. Tell them that there is no reason to give them your insurance policy number, that you feel the rental company is acting suspicious and to please refund your deposit immediately. If they will not immediately refund your money, tell them you are calling your credit card company to dispute your charge for the whole rental, that you are notifying their town's code enforcement office, filing a complaint with their state's consumer affairs office and the Better Business Bureau. As well as leaving them a bad review on Yelp and Google. That should get their attention.

Comment: A nice answer from a pro !